# Asp .Net Core 3.0 + Angular. Настройка и локализация страницы авторизации

Tags: asp.net-core, angular, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

Приложение Angular ASP Net Core создано на основе шаблона VS2019 .NetCore 3.0 с аутентификацией и локальным хранением учетных записей. Я хочу настроить и локализовать страницу авторизации (удалить некоторые поля ввода). Как это сделать?

Comment: используй интернационализацию которая идет из коробки angular, либо сторонние пакеты - ngx-translate и тд.

Comment: Как настроить страницу (изменить элементы)?

Comment: я не понимаю этого вопроса :(

Comment: При создании проекта ASP .Net Core 3.0 в VS2019 на основании шаблона Angular с аутентификацией "Учетные записи отдельных пользователей" создается заготовка проекта SPA. При этом страницы авторизации предлагаются готовые, со своими элементами и текстами. Вопрос: как до них добраться чтобы изменить?

Comment: ну наверное открыть файлы и начать добавлять то что нужно? ;D

Comment: где эти файлы? Сейчас пробую через Razor (подсказали на англ.)

Comment: angular- это отдельное приложение со своими шаблонами (не разоровскими)

Comment: Identity вроде как использует Razor